# Send Compressed Zip folders to email using Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm really new at coding. Everything I know has been done by research and YouTube tutorials. I've been trying to figure out how to attach a compressed zip folder to an email message that I'm sending to multiple email addresses using Google Sheets AppsScripts.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Abs of Steel Workout 002.zip')
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = "Good morning,\n"
    +"\n"
    +"Thank you for being with Team Dollar Gains Club! This month is based off super sets. Be sure to follow our social media on Instagram (@DollarGainsClub) and Facebook (facebook.com/dollargainsclub) for inspiration and motivation to kill your workout!\n"
    +"\n"
    +"Attached to this email are your 2 workout routines and How-To pictures demonstrating the proper technique to perform each exercise. Each routine shall be completed at least once a week for a period of 2 weeks, before moving onto the next routine.\n"
    +"\n"
    +"If you have any questions about anything, feel free to respond to this email whenever! We are here to help you reach all of your fitness goals. Let's get to it!\n"
    +"\n"
    +"Best regards,\n"
    +"Jordan Taylor\n"
    +"Founder of Dollar Gains Club\n"
    +"www.dollargainsclub.co";       
    var subject = "Dollar Gains Club Subscription: Chest Day";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: file.next().getBlob()});
  }
}
```

I'm not exactly certain what to do within the

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName( ' ' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a file named `Abs of Steel Workout 002.zip` that you want to send to everyone on your list. The command

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Abs of Steel Workout 002.zip')
```

returns not a file, but a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), since Google Drive allows multiple files with the same name. Every time the method `next` is called on this iterator, you get next file among these... but since you only have one, this throws an exception at the second run of the loop.

So, `next` should be called outside of the loop. And it's better to get a blob there too, since it's also the same for all messages. Just replace `var file=` with

```
var blob = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Abs of Steel Workout 002.zip').next().getBlob();
```

and in the loop you'll have simply

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: blob});
```

Comment: So I tried this but received the following error:                                                                         **TypeError: Cannot find function getBlob in object function next() {/* */}. (line 8, file "Code")**

Comment: I had a typo there: missing parentheses after `.next`. Corrected now.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it again and it's stating: **Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. (line 8, file "Code")** Any idea how come?

Comment: I'd check if you actually have the file named that way, 'Abs of Steel Workout 002.zip'

Comment: Haha it's funny how we skip the smallest things... it worked, thank you!! @404